# Classification of the Inside of a Grapefruit

Tags: everyday-chemistry, erratum

In the text Chemistry: The Central Science, the inside of a grapefruit is classified as a homogeneous mixture. Unless I’m missing something, to me it would be a heterogenous mixture owing to pulp, seeds, and ultimately the fact that cells are not homogenous. Is this a mistake in the text, and, if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Your interpretation sounds reasonable to me, but I’m no grapefruit expert. :-) If it’s physically separable, it’s definitely not homogenous.

Comment: Yes, it is heterogeneous (unless it's put into an ultrasonic cell disruptor... and even them I'd quibble).

Comment: Which edition are you working out of? Searching through the text of the 12th ed only shows one mention of grapefruit in the acid-base intro. If it's newer than 12th, then they added that part quite recently and hence wouldn't have had as much proofreading on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneity_and_heterogeneity):

> In chemistry, a heterogeneous mixture consists of either or both of a)
>   multiple states of matter or b) hydrophilic and hydrophobic substances
>   in one mixture

The inside of a grapefruit is clearly made up of multiple states of matter (solid and liquid), and is thus heterogeneous. Text books sometimes contain errors, and that appears to be the case here.